# Mouse pointer hover/jquery click event on SVG embedded in object element not working

Tags: jquery, css, svg, hover

I'm using jQuery to dynamically add an  element to display an SVG using this code:

```
someEl = ('#someElement');
cancelButton = $(document.createElement('object')).attr({
            'class': 'cancelButton',
            'id':parent_id+'_xbtn',
            'data': 'img/cancelBtn.svg',
            'type': 'image/svg+xml'
        });
someEl.after(cancelButton);

function cancel() {
    alert('asd');
}
cancelButton.click(cancel);
```

And I style it to hover with a hand using this CSS:

```
.cancelButton:hover {
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

However I found that firstly when I hover the element, the mouse pointer does not change. Hover effects which modify the element itself (e.g. change bg-color) work fine, though. Secondly, the jQuery click handler I attached does not fire either.

Is this some limitation of the `<object>` element or of how SVG works? Any comments or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: adding `cursor:pointer` after `cursor:hand` will set the cursor to pointer. Just remove `cursor:pointer` to fix that problem

Comment: and your `$(this)` call falls outside any function - unless this is just a result of the code snippet, this would mean $(this) refers to the global object, I think, which would not be what you want

Comment: That is a result of this being a code snippet, sorry. This is all inside a function, and it attaches after the element in question just fine.

`cursor: pointer` is the name used by modern browsers for the hand, but old IE uses `hand`, so both are needed. If I remove one it doesn't work in FF, Chrome, etc., and if I remove the other it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: I've removed the reference to $(this) for clarity.

Comment: You could create an ie-only class, a la html5 boilerplate: `<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->` then in that class specify the `hand` reference: `.ie { cursor: hand; }`

Comment: But the problem is that the cursor never changes when I hover the `<object>` with the SVG, regardless of the css. That CSS works fine with other elements in my code, just not with `<object>`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why that would be then.

Comment: Of course. Hope you find your answer

Comment: Apparently this embedding approach does not allow scripting according to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, SVG embedded as `<object>` elements tend to swallow pointer events (because the browser creates a new document inside the object element, similar to iframe). Is there a reason you can't just use an `<img>` tag? For example:

```
someEl = ('#someElement');
cancelButton = $('<img>').attr({
    'class': 'cancelButton',
    'id':parent_id+'_xbtn',
    'src': 'img/cancelBtn.svg'
});
someEl.after(cancelButton);

function cancel() {
    alert('clicked');
}
cancelButton.click(cancel);
```

**Edit:**

If you need to use an `<object>` tag (e.g. because your SVG file references external assets), my solution would be to create a transparent overlay div of same width and height, absolutely positioned over the top of the object, and bind events on that div instead.

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks! For now I've just saved a PNG of the SVG and have been using that.

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorry. This did work, but not in some older browsers, so I didn't go with it in my project, and I thought I'd accepted this already.